# React Native Inapp calender event setup

Tags: react-native

I have my app in react native and i have some upcoming events listed in my app and i want to let other people to set up a reminder in their calendar by providing them a button of get a reminder for this event in the app. Any idea?

i have already tried some plugins but it isn't helping with the automation.

But i need the automation to be like when the user clicks the GET REMINDER FOR THIS EVENT button in my app he should get redirected to the respective calender app and an event should set up automatically. But it didn't go that way.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

you can you package

```
react-native-calendar-events
```

to send your event information to the calender application. Once it's set calender application automatically gets a notification and all. Please use following [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-calendar-events)

Make sure ask all permission before save event.